# Does underscore's extend function extend recursively (or have the option of doing so)?

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

jQuery's extend function has the option of recursive extension, which I use when creating json config files. I can see that underscore has an [extend function](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend), but it doesn't even mention recursion. I assume this means it doesn't recursively extend, but I thought I'd ask here before implementing it into my project and wasting a lot of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive/deep extend/assign in Underscore.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843815/recursive-deep-extend-assign-in-underscore-js)

Comment: @dskrvk Wait... Isn't my question nearly a year older?

Comment: It is, but the other one has more/better answers and more votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, Underscore's `extend` does not recursively extend. The [implementation is rather simple](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L638):

```
_.extend = function(obj) {
  each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
    for (var prop in source) {
      obj[prop] = source[prop];
    }
  });
  return obj;
};
```

The most interesting part for you is what's inside the `for` loop, a simple non-recursive assignment:

```
obj[prop] = source[prop];
```

Comment: @Codemonkey: You could probably borrow jQuery's without too much difficulty though, I'd guess that `$.extend` would be fairly well isolated and easily extracted.

Comment: @Codemonkey: You might be able to patch it into Underscore as a [mixin](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#mixin) too, Underscore is pretty handy so there's no need to throw it all out just because of one deficiency :)

Comment: I figured I would try that, yes. I sorta fell in love with all the "is..." functions :-P