# Recursive/deep extend/assign in Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there any way to get Underscore.js [`extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function:

> Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the
>   destination object, and return the destination object. It's in-order,
>   so the last source will override properties of the same name in
>   previous arguments.

... to work recursively?

Actually, `query` property in `creditOperation` is going to completely override the `query` property defined in `baseOperation`:

```js
var url = require('url')
  , _ = require('underscore'),
  , baseOperation = {
        host: 'gateway.skebby.it',
        pathname: 'api/send/smseasy/advanced/http.php',
        protocol: 'https',
        query: {
            'username': 'foo',
            'password': 'bar',
        }
    };

var creditOperation = _.extend(baseOperation, {
    query: {
        'method': 'baz'
    }
});

console.log(url.format(creditOperation));
```

I'd like to obtain this `creditOperation`:

```js
{
    host: 'gateway.skebby.it',
    pathname: 'api/send/smseasy/advanced/http.php',
    protocol: 'https',
    query: {
        'username': 'foo',
        'password': 'bar',
        'method': 'baz'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add "deep" and "assign" words in your title so the thread can be easily found via Google. Like "Recursive/deep extend/assign in Underscore.js?"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Underscore has no plans to add a deep extend](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/162) since it's deemed too complicated to deal with different types of objects. Instead, users are encouraged to implement their own solutions with the support for what they need.

In your case it's only plain objects, so an implementation is quite straightforward:

```
_.deepObjectExtend = function(target, source) {
    for (var prop in source)
        if (prop in target)
            _.deepObjectExtend(target[prop], source[prop]);
        else
            target[prop] = source[prop];
    return target;
}
```

Comment: It seems this will throw an exception as-is when it hits a property that isn't an object. You need to verify that both target[prop] and source[prop] are objects before you try to recurse. Maybe something like `if (prop in target && typeof(target[prop]) == 'object' && typeof(source[prop]) == 'object')` for the third line instead.

Comment: Yeah, I expected this `extend` function to only extend (expand?) objects, not overwrite any properties in them (description says *only plain objects*). If you want that, `if (typeof target[prop] == 'object')` should be enough.

Comment: I'm not sure how having two objects with the same property makes them _not_ plain objects. This function is about 5x more useful if it handles objects with the same properties (and more in the spirit of _.extend). Also, only checking that the target[prop] is an object will still give (wildly) unexpected results in the case that the source prop is not an object and the target prop is: http://jsfiddle.net/wizzard/HY4yQ/ Admittedly, you might want to put some extra thought into this function if you have cases like that.

Comment: @wizzard: Sure, I have much more complex variations of the `extend` functionality in my personal lib - and this one here was not meant to be very generic. It just handles the use case from the question where the OP had (deeply nested) properties he wanted to mix in.

Comment: underscore will not, but its replacement [lodash](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#merge) has it, with its [`_.merge` function](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#merge), cf. @Paolo_Moretti comment : `_.merge(target, source)`

Answer (score 42):

With [Lodash](http://lodash.com/) (fork of underscore) you can.
there is the same function in *lodash* called [**_.merge**](https://lodash.com/docs#merge):

```
_.merge(a,b);
```

Comment: You can also use [`_.merge`](http://lodash.com/docs#merge): _Recursively merges own enumerable properties of the source object(s), that don't resolve to undefined into the destination object_.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: @wapsee, on the contrary, I think this is the most useful answer.

Answer (score 25):

jQuery has an [extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) function, which does the same thing as its Underscore counterpart, but also has a **deep** argument which allows it to merge recursively as you desire:

```
var creditOperation = $.extend(true, baseOperation, {
    query: {
        'method': 'baz'
    }
});
```

Or, if you don't want to overwrite *baseOperation*:

```
var creditOperation = $.extend(true, {}, baseOperation, {
    query: {
        'method': 'baz'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this one, it is preferably to use than write your own, anyway in many cases jquery is used in project.

Comment: This is what many people actually want when they find this page :)

Comment: the second one is the Million dollar answer!!! I can only give you +1 :)

Answer (score 9):

Stand-alone version of Bergi's deep extend, including the fix for when a value is a string instead of an object. Also patched to be more strict.

```
function deepObjectExtend (target, source) {
    for (var prop in source) {
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (target[prop] && typeof source[prop] === 'object') {
                deepObjectExtend(target[prop], source[prop]);
            }
            else {
                target[prop] = source[prop];
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kurt Milam has published a [mixin that adds a `deepExtend` method to underscore.js](https://gist.github.com/kurtmilam/1868955). It even deals with regular expressions (if you want).
Excerpt from the documentation:

> Mix it in with underscore.js:
> `_.mixin({deepExtend: deepExtend});`
>
> Call it like this: `var myObj = _.deepExtend(grandparent, child, grandchild, greatgrandchild)`
>
> Notes: Keep it DRY.
>
> This function is especially useful if you're working with JSON config documents. It allows you to create a default
> config document with the most common settings, then override those
> settings for specific cases. It accepts any number of objects as
> arguments, giving you fine-grained control over your config document
> hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

underscore's extend() does not do deep extend; as a matter of fact, there is no function in underscore which can deep extend.

You may use lodash's [merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) for that.