# Extend an object without destroying nested object attributes?

Tags: javascript

I have an object with some nested objects, I want to extend the object and in some cases the nested objects will be returned as empty although I'd like to preserve these - can anyone recommend how I can do this?

```
    let myObject = {
    id: 1,
    configs: {
        track: true,
        pulse: false
    },
    name: 'slider',
    position: 1
}

let updatedObject = Object.assign({}, myObject, {
    name: 'scroller',
    configs: {}
})

// outputs {id: 1, configs: {}, name: 'scroller', position: 1}
```

found this useful plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge

Comment: But you've specified `configs: {}`, so you are overriding it.

Comment: This is custom behavior you'll have to write yourself, basically recursively extending.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_.merge()` method from Lodash.

```js
let myObject = {
  id: 1,
  configs: {
    track: true,
    pulse: false
  },
  name: 'slider',
  position: 1
}

var update = _.merge({}, myObject, {
    name: 'scroller',
    configs: {}
})

console.log(update)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there an underscore alternative to this one? I tried extend but it performs same action as Object assign

Comment: I don't think there is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843815/recursive-deep-extend-assign-in-underscore-js

Answer (score 1):

```js
let myObject = {
  id: 1,
  configs: {
    track: true,
    pulse: false
  },
  name: 'slider',
  position: 1
}
let updatedObject = shallowAssignNonEmptyProperties(Object.assign({}, myObject), {
  name: 'scroller',
  configs: {}
}))

function shallowAssignNonEmptyProperties(target, source) {
  for (const prop in source) {
    const newValue = source[prop]
    if (typeof newValue !== 'object' || Object.keys(newValue).length) {
      target[prop] = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

When we want to skip specific properties, `Object.assign()` or `object spread` won't work. If you want to come up with a solution, it requires to iterate the properties, inspect the type of them and decide if you want that value to be assigned over.

- `typeof newValue !== 'object'`: we let pass values other than objects;
- `Object.keys(newValue).length`: check if the object is empty or have any properties;

This one is pretty simple, although if you need deep assignment/merge, you'll use a lib (lodash) or recursively call this function. It's up to you.

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*. (Also: This is all-or-nothing. What if the OP wants `configs: {track: false}` but wants the other config's `puse` property to come through? Really, it's up to the OP to write this code.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the input. hope it's more approppriate as it stands now. ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hey, does it looks alright? I've been here for quite a while but it's pretty uncommon to have feedback like this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nested properties are used as-is, they are not recursively assigned/merged. So the `configs` object is taken from the final argument of the `assign(...)` call (which is an empty object) and completely overrides the earlier values.